# What make is my bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I would like to cycle to my school but there are some questions that I can't answer like "Make of bicycle" , "Type of bike" and "Frame of bike" I would like it if someone could tell me.[image]

Comment: Do you need to fill in some kind of form before you can take the bike to school?

Comment: It looks like the handlebar stem has been pulled out to far, and how much seat post is below the clamp?  Both of these issues can make the bicycle dangerous to ride.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The make is Apollo and the model seems to be called Sand Storm.

It’s a (full suspension) mountain bike style bike, although it isn’t really strong enough to ride off-road much. Probably great fun for riding to and from school though.

I’m not sure what you would put for “Frame of bike” as it seems synonymous with “Type of bike” unless you need to know the frame number, which is likely to be found under the bottom bracket, the part of frame between the pedals.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will have a look for the frame number. Tomorrow morning as it is late at night where I live now. Also looking back at the question, it says "Frame/Serial number" and I thought it meant "Frame OR Serial-number". Have a nice day.

Comment: @RandomVideospleasedontjudg Yeah, they mean "Frame number aka serial number".

Comment: On most bikes now the serial number is stamped on the bottom of the "bottom bracket" -- the enclosure in which the crank turns.  Simply turn the bike upside down and it should be easy to see.